# jQuery checkbox drop down control

Tags: jquery-plugins

[link text](http://cid-3dbfac44f49def30.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/New%20album/untitled.JPG)hi,
  i am using jQuery checkbox drop down control. i am able to  bind the values to listbox and show the values .

i need to make certain items in my listbox[checkbox drop down control] non selectable.
i am  refering this website

http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/demo.html

i am using the JQuery plugin in to achive this . i am able to fix the height  of the control all these things are possiable. 
 i have an datatable with items

```
karnataka
tamilnaidu
kerla
------
delhi
mumbai
chennai
------
abc
poasda
sewqwq
qwewqe
------
```

so now if user tries to select the"------" values it should not  get selected

any help would be great

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding to these options the disabled attribute ?

```
<option value="..whatever.." disabled="disabled">------</option>
```

Comment: in listbox control u dnt have this option
<option value="..whatever.." disabled="disabled">------</option>

Comment: i am using list box control  and an datatable  whose vaues are comimg  from database

Comment: @prince23 aren't you using the select tag ? All the examples at the url you gave use the `<select>` tag to define the list.. and the select tag uses a list of `<option>` tags as the elements..